# How to include habtm relationship during serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a has_and_belongs_to_many association in my rails 3 app. I am also using the new respond_with method to automatically generate the XML for the REST API.

The HABTM association is between DataSource and Parameter and the join table is data_sources_parameters.

When I write `respond_with DataSource.all, :include => parameter`, it works and I get the expected response

```
<data-sources type="array">
<data-source>
<created-at type="datetime">2011-04-05T14:05:22Z</created-at>
<id type="integer">1</id>
<updated-at type="datetime">2011-04-05T14:05:22Z</updated-at>
<url>http://www.yahoo.com/weather</url>
<parameters type="array"/>
</data-source>
</data-sources>
```

The response indicates that parameters for each data source will be included with the data-source. However, this only works when there is no actual association existing yet i.e. the join table is empty.

The moment I actually create an association between two database entries, I get the error "undefined method `type' for nil:NilClass" and the log points to the above line of code.

Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?

Comment: You're using habtm in rails3? Why aren't you using `has_many :through`?

Comment: There is no other model which links DataSource and Parameter. How would you suggest to use has_many :through?

Comment: Sorry - I was under the impression that habtm was being deprecated - but it isn't. Your relationship definitely could be implemented as :through, but if you don't need to access any data on the join, there's no point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this?
[to_xml include doesn't work in rails 3.0.6 ruby 1.9.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661489/to-xml-include-doesnt-work-in-rails-3-0-6-ruby-1-9-2)